# Вставка большого html блока

Tags: jquery

Необходимо вставить в элемент большой html блок, сложность в том, что он содержит как одинарные, так и двойные кавычки. А значит .html() в привычном виде не вариант.

Comment: $('#block').load('/tmpl/html_block.php');

Answer (score 1):

А почему бы перед выдачей не экранировать строку? В php есть такая функция, как **[addslashes()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.addslashes.php)**. Вот и подготовьте до того, как собираетесь выводить на экран.

Answer (score 0):

Строка - это строка и неважно, какие там кавычки и в каком количестве.
Так что `.html` в руки и всё.

Ну или подумать (даже без бурундука).